# ¿Cómo utilizar correctamente numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matemáticas, math, calculo

Estoy utilizando la librería numpy para poder calcular el valor del seno y el coseno a través de la serie de taylor, para ello utilizo una lista de valores para los cuales quiero calcularle el seno y el coseno, sin embargo, a la hora de la implementación, a medida que van cambiando los valores de x a evaluar, el valor que estoy obteniendo a través de la serie de taylor empieza a crecer y salirse del rango de valores de la función seno y coseno, recordando que el rango de estas funciones es [-1,1]. Espero que puedan ayudarme por favor. Adjunto el código.

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
def Taylor(n,nums):
    senx=lambda x:np.sin(x)
    cosx=lambda x:np.cos(x)
    numsin,numcos=0,1
    listnumsen,listnumcos,lcos,lsen=[],[],[],[]
    for num in nums:
        for i in range(0,n):
            numsin=numsin+(((-1)**i)/(m.factorial(2*i+1))*num**(2*i+1))
            numcos=numcos+(((-1)**i)/(m.factorial(2*i))*num**(2*i))
        listnumsen.append(numsin)
        listnumcos.append(numcos)
        numsin=0
        numcos=0
        lsen.append(senx(num))
        lcos.append(cosx(num))
    print(listnumsen)
    print(lsen)
    print(listnumcos)
    print(lcos)

n=int(input("Cantidad de términos a utilizar: "))
nums=np.arange(0,9)
Taylor(n,nums)
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `nums`? Es una lista?

Comment: nums es una lista generada a través de la función arange, esta contiene valores desde 0 hasta 9